# Inheritance PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, inheritance, many-to-many

I have 2 tables under PostgreSQL:

a table property that is the mother table (id, created_at ..) and
a habitation table (surface, room, etc...) that inherits property. On the mother table, I have a many-many relationship table. I have added results in the "habitation" table.

When I try to insert "property_table" with habitation IDs, I have a SQL error telling me that the property_id ID does not exist. It exists when I go to see the property or habitation table. I want to insert habitation IDs (so property) in property_tag , should I force insert? Help please

The SQL schemas :

```
    CREATE TABLE "property"
    (
        id serial NOT NULL,
        created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
        updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
        address_id int NOT NULL,
        permission int NOT NULL DEFAULT 6,
        user_id int NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES "address"(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
    );
    CREATE TABLE habitation (
            total_surface float,
            living_surface float,
            ground_surface float,
            ground_surface_unity character varying(15) DEFAULT 'm2',
            room integer,
            bedroom integer,
            floor integer,
            level integer,
            year integer
        )  INHERITS (property);
   CREATE TABLE property_tag 
        (                
            tag_id int NOT NULL,
            property_id int NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, property_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES "tag"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES "property"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
        );

CREATE TABLE "tag"
            (
                id serial NOT NULL,
                created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
                updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
                name character varying(127) NOT NULL,
                user_id int NOT NULL,
                color character varying(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A4A4A8',
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
            );
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and the insert statement you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question - do **not** post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert into table "habitation", the row exists physically only in table "habitation", but not in "property".

Your table "property_tag" references to table "property" (which have no rows, cause rows are in table "habitation") and therefore you are getting error during insert.

You have to change your reference in table "property_tag" from "property" to "habitation".